# Flotchart da Error: Invalid dimensions for plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

Tengo el siguiente código que saqué de [una pregunta de stack overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231812/flot-chart-customizing-bars-with-labels-on-top):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d1_1 = [
    [1325376000000, 10],
    [1328054400000, 20],
    [1330560000000, 30],
    [1333238400000, 40],
    [1335830400000, 35]
  ];

  var d1_2 = [
    [1325376000000, 80],
    [1328054400000, 60],
    [1330560000000, 20],
    [1333238400000, 90],
    [1335830400000, 30]
  ];

  var data1 = [{
      label: "Product 1",
      data: d1_1,
      bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 12 * 44 * 60 * 60 * 300,
        fill: true,
        lineWidth: 0,
        order: 1,
        fillColor: {
          colors: ["#80C3FD", "#0089FF"]
        }
      },
      color: "rgba(243, 89, 88, 0.7)"
    },
    {
      label: "Product 2",
      data: d1_2,
      bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 12 * 44 * 60 * 60 * 300,
        fill: true,
        lineWidth: 0,
        order: 2,
        fillColor: {
          colors: ["#F39494", "#f14d4d"]
        }
      },
      color: "rgba(251, 176, 94, 0.7)"
    },

  ];

  $.plot($("#placeholder-bar-chart"), data1, {
    xaxis: {
      min: (new Date(2011, 11, 15)).getTime(),
      max: (new Date(2012, 04, 18)).getTime(),
      mode: "time",
      timeformat: "%b",
      tickSize: [1, "month"],
      //monthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
      tickLength: 0, // hide gridlines
      axisLabel: 'Month',
      axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
      axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
      axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
      axisLabelPadding: 5,
      ticks: [
        [1325376000000, 'Takaoma'],
        [1328054400000, 'Giacompany'],
        [1330560000000, 'FreshFields'],
        [1333238400000, 'Generalisimo'],
        [1335830400000, 'Greenleaves']
      ]
    },
    yaxis: {
      axisLabel: '%',
      axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
      axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
      axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
      axisLabelPadding: 5,
      tickSize: 10,
      tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
        return val + "%";
      },

    },
    grid: {
      hoverable: true,
      clickable: false,
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderColor: '#f0f0f0',
      labelMargin: 8,
    },
    series: {
      shadowSize: 1,

    },

    legend: {
      show: false,
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
      id: "chart-tooltip",
      content: "<p><b>20</b> Outgoing Filings</p>" +
        "<p>Out of <b>10</b> committed;</p>" +
        "<br />" +
        "<p><b>30%</b>% Ratio</p>",
      shifts: {
        x: -74,
        y: -125
      },
      lines: {
        track: true
      },
      compat: true,
    },


  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>

<div id="placeholder-bar-chart" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
```

Como verán me da un error que dice:

> Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 478, height = 0

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo corre´gi con algo de HTMl y CSS.

Básicamente uno debe de tener ya dimensionado el HTML, así que primero se mete todo en un `div`, en mi caso

```
<div class="chart-container">
```

a dicho div le puse dimensiones explícitamente, e hice que mi div de las gráficas se expandiera completamente

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d1_1 = [
    [1325376000000, 10],
    [1328054400000, 20],
    [1330560000000, 30],
    [1333238400000, 40],
    [1335830400000, 35]
  ];

  var d1_2 = [
    [1325376000000, 80],
    [1328054400000, 60],
    [1330560000000, 20],
    [1333238400000, 90],
    [1335830400000, 30]
  ];

  var data1 = [{
      label: "Product 1",
      data: d1_1,
      bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 12 * 44 * 60 * 60 * 300,
        fill: true,
        lineWidth: 0,
        order: 1,
        fillColor: {
          colors: ["#80C3FD", "#0089FF"]
        }
      },
      color: "rgba(243, 89, 88, 0.7)"
    },
    {
      label: "Product 2",
      data: d1_2,
      bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 12 * 44 * 60 * 60 * 300,
        fill: true,
        lineWidth: 0,
        order: 2,
        fillColor: {
          colors: ["#F39494", "#f14d4d"]
        }
      },
      color: "rgba(251, 176, 94, 0.7)"
    },

  ];

  $.plot($("#placeholder-bar-chart"), data1, {
    xaxis: {
      min: (new Date(2011, 11, 15)).getTime(),
      max: (new Date(2012, 04, 18)).getTime(),
      mode: "time",
      timeformat: "%b",
      tickSize: [1, "month"],
      //monthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
      tickLength: 0, // hide gridlines
      axisLabel: 'Month',
      axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
      axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
      axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
      axisLabelPadding: 5,
      ticks: [
        [1325376000000, 'Takaoma'],
        [1328054400000, 'Giacompany'],
        [1330560000000, 'FreshFields'],
        [1333238400000, 'Generalisimo'],
        [1335830400000, 'Greenleaves']
      ]
    },
    yaxis: {
      axisLabel: '%',
      axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
      axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
      axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
      axisLabelPadding: 5,
      tickSize: 10,
      tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
        return val + "%";
      },

    },
    grid: {
      hoverable: true,
      clickable: false,
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderColor: '#f0f0f0',
      labelMargin: 8,
    },
    series: {
      shadowSize: 1,

    },

    legend: {
      show: false,
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
      id: "chart-tooltip",
      content: "<p><b>20</b> Outgoing Filings</p>" +
        "<p>Out of <b>10</b> committed;</p>" +
        "<br />" +
        "<p><b>30%</b>% Ratio</p>",
      shifts: {
        x: -74,
        y: -125
      },
      lines: {
        track: true
      },
      compat: true,
    },


  });

});
```

```css
.demo-placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chart-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
  <div id="placeholder-bar-chart" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error es muy claro: No se puede mostrar la gráfica por que las dimensiones son inválidas y, como no hay un parámetro o propiedad donde especificarlo, podemos suponer que se trata del tamaño del contenedor.

Solución: Asignar las medidas deseadas desde CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d1_1 = [
    [1325376000000, 10],
    [1328054400000, 20],
    [1330560000000, 30],
    [1333238400000, 40],
    [1335830400000, 35]
  ];

  var d1_2 = [
    [1325376000000, 80],
    [1328054400000, 60],
    [1330560000000, 20],
    [1333238400000, 90],
    [1335830400000, 30]
  ];

  var data1 = [{
      label: "Product 1",
      data: d1_1,
      bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 12 * 44 * 60 * 60 * 300,
        fill: true,
        lineWidth: 0,
        order: 1,
        fillColor: {
          colors: ["#80C3FD", "#0089FF"]
        }
      },
      color: "rgba(243, 89, 88, 0.7)"
    },
    {
      label: "Product 2",
      data: d1_2,
      bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 12 * 44 * 60 * 60 * 300,
        fill: true,
        lineWidth: 0,
        order: 2,
        fillColor: {
          colors: ["#F39494", "#f14d4d"]
        }
      },
      color: "rgba(251, 176, 94, 0.7)"
    },

  ];

  $.plot($("#placeholder-bar-chart"), data1, {
    xaxis: {
      min: (new Date(2011, 11, 15)).getTime(),
      max: (new Date(2012, 04, 18)).getTime(),
      mode: "time",
      timeformat: "%b",
      tickSize: [1, "month"],
      //monthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
      tickLength: 0, // hide gridlines
      axisLabel: 'Month',
      axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
      axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
      axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
      axisLabelPadding: 5,
      ticks: [
        [1325376000000, 'Takaoma'],
        [1328054400000, 'Giacompany'],
        [1330560000000, 'FreshFields'],
        [1333238400000, 'Generalisimo'],
        [1335830400000, 'Greenleaves']
      ]
    },
    yaxis: {
      axisLabel: '%',
      axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
      axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
      axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
      axisLabelPadding: 5,
      tickSize: 10,
      tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
        return val + "%";
      },

    },
    grid: {
      hoverable: true,
      clickable: false,
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderColor: '#f0f0f0',
      labelMargin: 8,
    },
    series: {
      shadowSize: 1,

    },

    legend: {
      show: false,
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
      id: "chart-tooltip",
      content: "<p><b>20</b> Outgoing Filings</p>" +
        "<p>Out of <b>10</b> committed;</p>" +
        "<br />" +
        "<p><b>30%</b>% Ratio</p>",
      shifts: {
        x: -74,
        y: -125
      },
      lines: {
        track: true
      },
      compat: true,
    },


  });

});
```

```css
html, body {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

#placeholder-bar-chart {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>

<div id="placeholder-bar-chart" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
```

**Nota:** Si solo corriges las medidas, vas a ver un error de plugin `flot.time` requerido y lo puedes obtener desde `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.min.js`, que ya está agregado en este fragmento de código.

Comment: ¿Por qué le pones dimensiones al HTML y al Body?

Comment: Solo para el ejemplo, si el contenedor padre (HTML y body) no tienen medidas específicas, asignar 100% de altura no tiene efecto.

Comment: entonces en vez de 100% se le podría agregar el valor en pixels y debería funcionar. Genial.

Comment: Es correcto, con medidas fijas en vez de relativas funciona sin problema.